# Is it possible to run 2 sbt projects at the same time?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have 2 sbt projects that are runnable (akka app and another play application).

Is it possible to run both of them, and use ~reStart so they refresh on any changes to my project?

Any tips on doing this correctly so I don't run out of memory also?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Play Framework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/PlayConsole)'s latest version you can `~run` without any plugin. Regarding standalone akka application you may use a library called [sbt-revolver](https://github.com/spray/sbt-revolver)

```
runAkkaServer := {
  (reStart in Compile in `akka-server`).evaluated
}

runWebServer := {
  (~run in Compile in `web-server`).evaluated
}

mainClass in reStart := Some("com.example.MainAkka")

val runAkkaServer = inputKey[Unit]("Runs akka-server")
val runWebServer = inputKey[Unit]("Runs web-server")
```

NOTE: you can run both applications in restart mode without custom tasks:
 1. `~run` - Play server
 2. `reStart` - Standalone

UPDATE:

I've tried to use following command to both of them, it seems that sbt-revolver is kinda trick and killing  application onstart. When replace `reStart` with `run` it works perfect, but doesn't trigger changes.

```
 screen -d -m sbt runAppServer; screen -d -m sbt runWebServer
```

So above code just doesnot behave as expected. Instead of custom tasks, we can run them in separate windows like this:

```sh
screen -dmS "appserver" sh -c "sbt 'project appserver;~reStart'; exec bash" ;  screen -dmS "webserver" sh -c "sbt runWebServer; exec bash"
```

Also `sbt runWebServer` can be replaced by `sbt 'project anothersubmodule;~run'` if you wish.

I've created a simple demonstration project, you can find [here](https://github.com/Bunyod/multimodulerunner)
In order to start you can call just: `./starter.sh`

NOTE: you can install `screen` command if you don't have easily.

Comment: I think doing it manually, I have to open 2 seperate sbt consoles and that easts memory and one sometimes locks the other.

Comment: do you mind explaining this?  How does inputKey[Unit] work?

Comment: thanks, btw that refactoring with cats repo you have, is that based on a book/video?

Comment: which one? Do you mean PracticalFPinScala? If so, yes it's based on a book

Comment: Haha, it's combination of different sources. Main insight regarding cats from "Advance Scala with Cats book"

Answer (score 0):

Open two different Terminal tabs; *cd* into the specific directory in each tab and then run with SBT.

```
sbt run
```

For multiple web apps, specify a different port:

```
sbt run -Dhttp.port=8888
```