# Sbt run multiple projects is not possible due to waiting on sbt lock

Tags: scala, sbt

I have multiple runnable projects under the root `build.sbt` which I intended to run with `sbt run` command.

Here is how my `build.sbt` looks like:

```
lazy val prj1 = (project in file("prj1"))

lazy val prj2 = (project in file("prj2"))
```

The problem is running `sbt "project prj1" run` and then `sbt "project prj2" run` makes `prj2` to wait on the lock:

```
[info] waiting for lock on /Users/usrname/.sbt/boot/sbt.boot.lock to be available...
```

But I'd like to run both of the project simultaneously since there is some integration between them.

Is it possible to do? Some workarounds?

Comment: If you need to run 2 projects at once try https://index.scala-lang.org/spray/sbt-revolver

Comment: You may also want to check if using **sbtn** would help.

Comment: You might also consider having a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59186025/how-to-run-multiple-sbt-projects-in-parallel and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61085900/is-it-possible-to-run-2-sbt-projects-at-the-same-time